# Сбросить значение в модели, если в ComboBox его больше нету

Tags: wpf

Предположим, имеется форма, содержащая ComboBox, который заполняется данными из БД.

При закрытии формы модель куда-то сохраняет ID выбранного элемента.

При последующих открытиях формы все хорошо, так как в ComboBox отображается сохраненное в предыдущем сеансе значение.

Однако, проблемы начинаются если значение пропало из БД.

В ComboBox ничего не отображается - это верно, НО в модели это значение по прежнему сохранено.

Можно ли автоматически обнулять значение в забинженном свойстве, если такого нету уже в `ComboBox`?

Comment: Если конкретного ID нет при запуске, вы же об этом знаете, верно? Так почему бы не проверять актуальность сохранённого значения при запуске, сверяя его с актуальными данными из бд?

Comment: Можно, но может быть это решается 1 атрибутом в XAML.

Comment: Нет такого атрибута